# How to get the frequency of specific substring through out the rows (words) in a sentence in R?

Tags: r

if I have a vector

```
x <- c("aa/bb","cc/aa","aa/dd", "bb/cc")
```

I want to get a output for specif substrings such as for "aa" and "bb":

```
aa = 3
bb = 2
```

This frequency can be calculated of irrespective of the position.
Kindly let me know do we have a function for this or we need to write a separate function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could split `x` at `/` and use `table` to count the frequency.

```
table(unlist(strsplit(x, "/")))

#aa bb cc dd 
# 3  2  2  1
```

If you want to count specific substrings, you could do

```
library(stringr)
sapply(c("aa", "bb"), function(ss) sum(str_count(x, ss)))
#aa bb 
# 3  2
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked for the component.